# Developing an application for IE6-7 in a short timeframe : which tools?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, local

I've been tasked with developing an application for internal use in our company, the end-users being the operators of the call center and their superviser.

There would be therefore be two types of users: operator & supervisor.

The operator view would be purely passive: ability to see their monthly goals (calls taken, calls answered etc) as well as those of their "cell"(group of operators+supervisor) and other "cells" and that's it.

The supervisor one however would be able active: they need to be able to set monthly goals for their subordinates as well as view them.

The application needs to live in the browser, and that browser is...*sigh*, either IE6 or IE7. So my question is, should I use something client-side like backbone.js, or something server-side like, say, Code Igniter?

I need to be able to develop it in a short time frame and add features as requested.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Choose what you know and like the best, but I wouldn't choose anything too client-side centric, because IE6 is so old and buggy that you'll hit walls. I would stick to simple server-generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, IE6 is very old. It is still supported but support will end fairly soon (about a year, I think), so your company *needs* to have an upgrade plan in place. IE7 has a bit longer to run, but will also fall out of support at some point. Your company *must* make plans for an upgrade process. And you need to make sure that anything you write today will continue working on upgraded browser versions when they come.

Okay, that aside, today you need to support these browsers.

The first advice I would give is to use jQuery for all your Javascript needs. It is specifically targeted at being compatible with IE6 and above, and it hides a lot of the complexities with cross-browser and old-browser support from the developer, but also works well with newer browsers too.

IE6/7 do have a number of serious bugs and omissions in their Javascript support, but these can generally be worked around. Using jQuery will mean you can forget about most of them.

In the main, I would recommend against using a client-side framework like Backbone. Stick with server-driven simple HTML pages. Maybe a bit of ajax using jQuery, but nothing too much more than that. IE6 and IE7 are very very slow browsers, so the less work you make them do, the happier they'll be. Put too much Javascript on the front end and you could wind up with a system that is too slow to be usable. Also, a lot of modern JS libraries don't support IE6 at all. I'm not sure about Backbone, but even if it works now, you can't be sure that later versions will continue supporting it. (even with jQuery, some developers are starting to push for IE6 to be dropped. I don't think it'll happen just yet though)

Make sure you specify a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` for all your pages. Without it, IE will drop into quirks mode. This will make it very difficult to upgrade your site to a newer browser later on. There are many valid doctypes, but it doesn't really matter which one you use, as long as it's valid. Therefore, I suggest using the HTML5 doctype, simply because it's valid and it's short and simple: `<!DOCTYPE html>` -- that's all there is to it.

CSS is where you'll really have some pain if you're used to working with modern browsers. IE6 in particular has terrible CSS support. For IE6/7 CSS compatibility, I recommend using the [Quirksmode.org compatibility charts](http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) to find out what does and does not work in those browsers.

Finally, make sure you read up on the well known IE6 bugs. There are a lot of them, and they often cause weird and wonderful rendering errors on perfectly valid code. Knowing about them in advance will help you avoid them, and help you recognise them when you (inevitably) hit them.

Hope that helps.

Oh, and good luck -- it sounds like you'll need it! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Developing websites or web applications for Internet Explorer 6 is possible as long as you do not use things such as HTML5 Javascript functions.

As for the live part, maybe you could use AJAX long polling or something similar. Example: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Hope this helps!